# Windows 8 linked email account was wrong - how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-8-mail-app

I entered the wrong email when I started my new Windows 8 laptop, and now I'm not able to change or cancel it.

Adding a new account didn't work, because it needs the registration confirmation mail.

How can I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: in the PC settings, go to the Users tab, and click on Switch to a local account. This will remove any reference to a Microsoft account. You can then try and switch to a Microsoft account later.

If this solution doesn't work, since the computer is new, you could perform a Reset: in the PC settings, go to the General tab and scroll down till "Reset your PC and start over".

Comment: Someone in the office just had the same problem, I could not *believe* that they utterly failed by not including a Back button -- and now they have to complete the setup and then do it all over again?! Back/Forward control is such a basic thing to include on any form-based setup. Incredulous.